# Comments on Nominations — Location Not Showed

Tags: bug, comments, users, election, profile-page

Puzzling.SE is currently holding a moderator election. 
During the nomination phase,
members were able to post [comments on nominations](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=nomination#comment-111235), like this:

[image: nominations page]

If you go to the [user profile page of somebody who posted such comment(s)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/39/doorknob?tab=activity&sort=comments),
you will see the comments and the date they were posted
(and the time, if you hover over the date):

[image: user profile page]

However, it doesn’t show *where* the comment was posted. 
Note, in the image above, that the top three comments are on nominations. 
The green boxes indicate the (blank) places
where the location of the comment should be displayed. 
(The blue oval shows that comments on regular posts
are linked to the posts where they appear.)

Comments on nominations should

- at the *very* least, state that they are comments on nominations,
- link to the comment (like [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=nomination#comment-111235)),
  or at least to the election (nomination) page,
- ideally, *state* whose nomination they are posted to.